# How can I prevent my main application window getting black?

Tags: 12.04, application-development, quickly, python-2.7

I have made an ubuntu app using `Quickly` in Ubuntu12.04.In that app's main 
window there are several buttons.Clicking some of them opens new windows of 
other applications(like, firefox,gnome-sound-recorder) and clicking
some of them runs commands in the background(like, html2text,espeak ).
Suppose I have clicked a button which opens Sound Recorder.Now if I start 
recording in the Sound Recorder my main application window gets black. Again 
when sound recording is done and I close the Sound Recorder window,
it becomes normal.
I think this part of my code is responsible for this:

```
os.system('gnome-sound-recorder')
```

What statement(s) should I use instead of the above-mentioned one to prevent 
my main application window going black?

I have tried using the following statements:

```
child_pid = os.fork()
if child_pid == 0:
    os.system('gnome-sound-recorder')
else:
    return
```

Now, the main app window doesn't get black.But, now if I close Sound Recorder
my main app window gets closed.What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to look at the subprocess module which allows you to spawn new processes without hanging your main app until they quit.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html